# How to remove deleted file from git-lens VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlens

[image: Vs Code Git-Lens]

How can I removed these deleted files from git lens using vs code

Comment: add them as Changes, and commit the changes of deleting files

Answer (score 2):

Those files are versioned on the remote repository, but you deleted them locally (that's why you see them among changed files). If you commit those deleted files and push them, you'll see them disappear both from your PC and the remote repository.

In case you don't want deleted files to be shown among changed ones, I'm afraid you can't achieve that in GitLens, but you could do it via console with: `git diff --name-status --diff-filter=d`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you want to continue using version control; you want to delete those files locally, while keeping them in the remote repository, but not have the files appear in the Source Control panel? Alternatively, can you further describe your goal? Another possible solution would be to add these files to a local gitignore file.